# toggle() function making link vibrating when click on it

Tags: jquery

I am using j query toggle() function, its not working as it is supposed to. Actually i am switch to form by toggling them with each other i.e hide the first and display the other.

```
$(".toggleForms").click(function () {

$("#signUpForm").toggle();
$("#logInForm").toggle());
});
```

I also tried this code:

```
$(".toggleForms").click(function (e) {

e.preventDefault();
$("#signUpForm").toggle();
$("#logInForm").toggle());
    });
```

it worked at that time but when i tried to right another function which is actually binding the content of a textarea and changing it after righting it down.

```
$("#diary").bind("input propertychange", function() {
alert ('changed');
});
```

Now when i tried to click on the text area it take me down to the login page instead of changing the text.

Comment: Could you show a working demo of the issue in a snippet and provide more information than 'it doesn't work'. What does it do? What should it do?. There's no reason why this shouldn't be working, assuming your HTML and JS is correctly configured.

Comment: That last bind function looks a little strange to me. The first parameter should be the event instead of `input propertychange`. As of version 3.0 `.bind()` has been deprecated btw, so you might want to start using `.on()` instead. That's not related to your question though :)